# Matplotlib animate doesn't appear to run function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, jupyter

I'm trying to create a plot that animates the line plot. I've created static versions of the same data happily, but nothing I do creates an animated plot. I have a dataframe could df_output that contains the dates as the index and different columns for the data itself. I've tried this which just creates an empty plot in Jupyter that doesn't update:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def animate(i, data_lst):
    data_lst.append(df_output.iloc[i,1])
    
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(data_lst)
    
    ax.set_ylim(0, max(data_lst))
    ax.set_title('Test title')
    ax.set_ylabel('Test label')

    
data_lst = []

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=100, fargs=(data_lst), interval=100)

plt.show()
```

Am I missing something obvious? I tried the code in Spyder and it's suggesting that I'm not actually calling the matplotlib.animation library? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this is a bit of a funny one, but `([])` is not a one-length tuple, `([],)` is.  In the above replace `fargs=(data_lst,)` is all you need to get it to work.  Or just use `fargs=[data_lst]` instead of a tuple.

Comment: Thank you! One day I will learn whether to use () or []....